# WCF REST POST JSON - The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

Tags: c#, wcf, json, rest, linq-to-entities

I am trying to post data to WCF REST service and  I keep getting the error The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
My code is as follows

ServiceContract:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="AppointmentService")]
public interface IAppointmentService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/edit", Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    string UpdateAppointment(AppointmentContract appointmentEntity);
}
```

Service:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class FrontOfficeRest:IAppointmentService
{
    #region Appointments
    public string UpdateAppointment(AppointmentContract appointmentEntity)
    {
        AppointmentList appList = new AppointmentList();
        appList = appointmentDAO.GetAllAppointmentsByDocotorAndDate(Convert.ToInt32(appointmentEntity.doctorId), Convert.ToDateTime(appointmentEntity.appointmentDate));
        if (appList.Count > 0)
        {
            var chApp = appList
                .Where(a => TimeSpan.Parse(a.startTime) == TimeSpan.Parse(appointmentEntity.startTime)
                    || (TimeSpan.Parse(a.startTime) < TimeSpan.Parse(appointmentEntity.startTime)
                    && TimeSpan.Parse(a.endTime) > TimeSpan.Parse(appointmentEntity.startTime)))
                .Select(a => a);

            if (chApp.Count() > 0)
                throw new WebFaultException<string>(string.Format("The Doctor is not available between {0} and {1}", appointmentEntity.startTime, appointmentEntity.endTime), HttpStatusCode.Conflict);
        }
        bool updResult = appointmentDAO.UpdateAppointment(appointmentEntity);
        OutgoingWebResponseContext ctx = WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse;
        string retRes = string.Empty;
        if (!updResult)
        {
            ctx.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotModified;
            retRes = "FAIL";
        }
        else
        {
            retRes = "SUCESS";
            ctx.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
        }
        return retRes;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

ClientCode

```
            string address = "http://localhost:8080/FrontOfficeRest/AppointmentService/edit";
            Uri uri = new Uri(address);
            RestClientUtility utl = new RestClientUtility();

            utl.ExecuteRequest<string>(uri, "POST", appointment);

    public void ExecuteRequest<T>(Uri uri, string method, object data)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = method;
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(data.GetType());
        JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string dataAsString = oSerializer.Serialize(data);
        byte[] byteData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataAsString);
        request.ContentLength = byteData.Length;

        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            //requestStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
            serializer.WriteObject(requestStream, data);
        }
        try
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                DataContractJsonSerializer deserializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                //result = (T)deserializer.ReadObject(responseStream);
            }
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            using (WebResponse response = e.Response)
            {
                HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
                Console.WriteLine("Error code: {0}", httpResponse.StatusCode);
                using (Stream datat = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    string text = new StreamReader(datat).ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(text);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

ServiceHost:

```
        string httpUri = "http://localhost:8080/FrontOfficeRest/";
        WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding();
        binding.MaxBufferSize = 4194304;
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 4194304;
        WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(FrontOfficeRest));
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IAppointmentService), binding, httpUri + "AppointmentService");
        Console.WriteLine("Appointment Service");
```

I get the error while processing the request 
    using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)

I am using Windows 7 IIS 7.0 There is no config file.
Can anyone help?

This is the stack trace

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
<System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
<EventID>131076</EventID>
<Type>3</Type>
<SubType Name="Error">0</SubType>
<Level>2</Level>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-11-01T12:28:21.6198391Z" />
<Source Name="System.ServiceModel" />
<Correlation ActivityID="{478927bf-de68-45f7-8c95-be1436cd00a9}" />
<Execution ProcessName="ConsoleTest" ProcessID="4792" ThreadID="4" />
<Channel />
<Computer>SIDDHARTH</Computer>
</System>
<ApplicationData>
<TraceData>
<DataItem>
<TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error">
<TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceHandledException.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
<Description>Handling an exception.</Description>
<AppDomain>ConsoleTest.exe</AppDomain>
<Exception>
<ExceptionType>System.NotSupportedException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.DefaultTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.UnaryTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, UnaryExpression linq)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.EqualsTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, BinaryExpression linq)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input, DbExpressionBinding&amp; binding)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression&amp; source, DbExpressionBinding&amp; sourceBinding, DbExpression&amp; lambda)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression&amp; source, DbExpressionBinding&amp; sourceBinding, DbExpression&amp; lambda)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SelectTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.UnarySequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.Convert()
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable&lt;T&gt;.GetEnumerator()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.&lt;GetElementFunction&gt;b__3[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression)
at System.Linq.Queryable.Single[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
at Orbitech.FrontOfficeDAL.AppointmentDAO.UpdateAppointment(AppointmentContract appointmentEntity) in D:\RestSample\Orbitech.FrontOffice\FrontOfficeDAL\AppointmentDAO.cs:line 127
at Orbitech.FrontOfficeRestful.FrontOfficeRest.UpdateAppointment(AppointmentContract appointmentEntity) in D:\RestSample\Orbitech.FrontOffice\FrontOfficeRestful\FrontOfficeRest.cs:line 75
at SyncInvokeUpdateAppointment(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]&amp; outputs)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.DefaultTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.UnaryTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, UnaryExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.EqualsTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, BinaryExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input, DbExpressionBinding&amp; binding)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression&amp; source, DbExpressionBinding&amp; sourceBinding, DbExpression&amp; lambda)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression&amp; source, DbExpressionBinding&amp; sourceBinding, DbExpression&amp; lambda)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SelectTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.UnarySequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.Convert()
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable&lt;T&gt;.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.&lt;GetElementFunction&gt;b__3[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Single[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
   at Orbitech.FrontOfficeDAL.AppointmentDAO.UpdateAppointment(AppointmentContract appointmentEntity) in D:\RestSample\Orbitech.FrontOffice\FrontOfficeDAL\AppointmentDAO.cs:line 127
   at Orbitech.FrontOfficeRestful.FrontOfficeRest.UpdateAppointment(AppointmentContract appointmentEntity) in D:\RestSample\Orbitech.FrontOffice\FrontOfficeRestful\FrontOfficeRest.cs:line 75
   at SyncInvokeUpdateAppointment(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]&amp; outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</ExceptionString>
</Exception>
</TraceRecord>
</DataItem>
</TraceData>
</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

Comment: To help answer this, can you post the HTTP request you sent to the server and the response it returned - that's the information which matters.

Comment: Try enabling tracing at the service. The traces will have an exception which will explain why the server considered the request to be bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@SIDDHARTH if you see the stack trace you will see Exception message as

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

In your service class unser the method UpdateAppointment you will find the below code
Convert.ToInt32(appointmentEntity.doctorId)

Convert the String value into Int32 before initializing appList as shown below
int doctorId = Convert.ToInt32(appointmentEntity.doctorId)

This is a shortcomming of LINQ to Entities

For detail explaination check http://blog.dreamlabsolutions.com/post/2008/11/17/LINQ-Method-cannot-be-translated-into-a-store-expression.aspx